# The WebDriver creation is blocked

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have seen lot of example to make test in Selenium and Ruby.
Here the code I'm trying :

```
  require 'selenium-webdriver'

  browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
  browser.get "http://google.com"

  ...
```

But the program is blocked at this line : `browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox`.

I have launch it with netbeans and irb => same problem.

With debug, I see I'is blocked here :

```
  # firefox.rb
  unless defined? SocketError
    class SocketError < IOError; end
  end
```

But I don't understand why.

I have installed the selenium driver with gem install. 
And other thing to do ?
Anybody see why the program is blocked ?

Comment: Give us the full error stack..

Comment: "Blocked" means what?

Comment: Blocked means nothing happend. And no error stack. If I don't kill the program, I have a nice "blue screen" of windows.

Comment: I just have tested the same operation on windows 7, it's working good.
I'm on W. XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finded the problem !

With debug mode, I have seen Selenium is checking that all interface are free (file port_prober.rb) :

```
def self.free?(port)
  Platform.interfaces.each do |host|
    begin
      TCPServer.new(host, port).close
    rescue *IGNORED_ERRORS => ex
      $stderr.puts "port prober could not bind to #{host}:#{port} (#{ex.message})" if $DEBUG
      # ignored - some machines appear unable to bind to some of their interfaces
    end
  end
  true
rescue SocketError, Errno::EADDRINUSE
  false
end
```

If the check failed, it is retried and if an exception is raised, the check is stopped.
On my computer, I have a problem on one interface and a **SocketError** is raised. But in this case, no error is raised, only a "not free" flag. So the check never stop.

I have made a correction

```
def self.free?(port)
  Platform.interfaces.each do |host|
    begin
      TCPServer.new(host, port).close
    rescue *IGNORED_ERRORS => ex
      $stderr.puts "port prober could not bind to #{host}:#{port} (#{ex.message})" if $DEBUG
      # ignored - some machines appear unable to bind to some of their interfaces
    rescue SocketError, Errno::EADDRINUSE
      $stderr.puts "port prober could not bind to #{host}:#{port} (#{ex.message})" if $DEBUG
      # ignored - some machines appear unable to bind to some of their interfaces
    end
  end
  true
end
```

I raise an error when there is a socketError.
I don't know why Selenium don't make that.
I will post it on Selenium bug tracker.

Thanks for your help.

Eric